# Combine multiple BehaviorSubject streams into one?

Tags: dart, rxdart

The goal is for me to use multiple streams without having to nest 3+ StreamBuilders.

I'm already using rxdart and I looked into mergewith but I don't really understand the proper syntax of using it?

I currently have a Bloc file titled `InfoBloc`. This is the code inside `InfoBloc`

```
  final _name = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _description = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _picture = BehaviorSubject<File>();

  Observable<String> get name => _name.stream.transform(_validateName);
  Observable<File> get picture => _picture.stream;
  Observable<String> get eventDescription =>
      _description.stream.transform(_validateMessage);

  final _validateMessage = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (eventMessage, sink) {
    if (eventMessage.length > 0) {
      sink.add(eventMessage);
    } else {
      sink.addError(StringConstant.eventValidateMessage);
    }
  });

  var obs = Observable.merge([])
  final _validateName = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (String name, sink) {
    if (RegExp(r'[!@#<>?":_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%0-9-]').hasMatch(name)) {
      sink.addError(StringConstant.nameValidateMessage);
    } else {
      sink.add(name);
    }
  });

  void dispose() async {
    await _description.drain();
    _description.close();
    await _name.drain();
    _name.close();
    await _picture.drain();
    _picture.close();
  }
```

Now inside of a widget, I need the name, picture, and description snapshot. So I would normally do

```
 StreamBuilder(
   stream: _bloc.name,
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshotName) {
     return StreamBuilder(
       stream: _bloc.eventDescription,
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshotDescription) {
         return StreamBuilder(
           stream: _bloc.picture,
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshotName) {
```

But there has got to be a better way of doing this.

The dream is that I can make something inside the `InfoBloc` file that can combine all these streams and I only have to use StreamBuilder once to stream that combined stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `combineLatest()` method for the `Observable` class. It merges the given Streams into one Observable sequence by using the combiner function such that the resulting Observable won't emit unless all the Streams have emitted atleast one item.

There are a bunch of `combineLatest()` methods. But since you have 3 Streams you can use `combineLatest3()`.

Example -

```
Observable.combineLatest3(
  new Observable.just("a"),
  new Observable.just("b"),
  new Observable.fromIterable(["c", "c"]),
  (a, b, c) => a + b + c)
.listen(print); //prints "abc", "abc"
```

You can check [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/combineLatest3.html) link for more information.

**UPDATE -**

You can refer to the below example for using the funciton in your code.

```
Observable<String> get name => _name.stream.transform(_validateName);
Observable<File> get picture => _picture.stream;
Observable<String> get eventDescription => _description.stream.transform(_validateMessage);
//Add this line to combine your Streams
Observable<bool> readyToSubmit => Observable.combineLatest3(name, picture, eventdescription, (value1, value2, value3) => true);
//We simply return true from the combiner function since we don't want to perform any operation on the Streams when combining.
```

I have used a `bool` type `Observable` just for example. You can change the type to `Map<String, dynamic>' and add the Stream values into the`Map`if you want to access the data from all three streams. And in your`StreamBuilder` widget you can use -

```
StreamBuilder(
   stream: _bloc.readyToSubmit,
   builder: //Your builder function here
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what happens if only a smaller subset of streams emit items, for eg only 2 streams emit and 3rd stream never emits...does the combined stream not have any result then?

Comment: Yes the combined stream won't emit a result unless every Stream has emitted atleast once. You can refer to this [marble diagram](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) for a better understanding.
If you're not sure about any one of the Streams emitting data, then you only combine two using `combineLatest2()` and use the third one separately.

Comment: is there no solution for when you're not sure if a stream emits or not? do you always have to test the streams? sorry for the beginner question,am a reactive programming noob

Comment: You could use the `startsWith()` method to make sure your Observable has some initial data and then you can use the `comineLatest()` method. More about this [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/startWith.html).

Comment: Appreciate the example and comments! My only question is where would I put this? and when you wrote (a,b,c) => a + b + c, how does it know what a, b, and c are? and how would I use this instead of StreamBuilder?

Comment: I'll update my answer with another example which you can use in your code with appropriate changes.

Comment: @SiddharthPatankar i believe I need to add `get` before readyToSubmit`, and I get errors when I added the (value) part

Comment: My apologies I forgot to write the `get` keyword. As for the value part, I'm not sure what errors you're getting. The solution I posted was working on my device.

Answer (score 1):

I used this with [`rxdart`](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart):

```dart
Rx.combineLatest2(behaviorSubject1, behaviorSubject2, (String mail, String subject) {
      return (mail.isNotEmpty && subject.isNotEmpty);
    }).listen((event) {
      event ? _enableButton.add(true) : _enableButton.add(false);
    });
```